# Подключение к websocket через раз

Tags: php, javascript, websocket

К webSocket через родной класс JS подключается через раз (сервер Ratchet там все работает прекрасно и отображает клиента при подключении так и его дисконнект). В чем может быть проблема и как с ней бороться?

Comment: Неплохо бы подробей рассказывать ..пошагово...какой код? какой браузер?...что получаешь и что ожидаешь?